# Is there such a thing as a function template template parameter?

Tags: c++, templates, template-templates, function-template

So I know C++ has a feature called "template template parameters", where you can pass a class template as a template parameter. For example:

```
template <typename T>
class vector { ... };

template <template <typename> class container>  // this is a template template parameter
class foo { ...  };

...

foo<vector> f;  // pass the vector template itself as template parameter
```

Is there an analogous thing for function templates? I.e. is there a way to pass a function template (for example, `std::make_pair`) as a template parameter to a class?

Comment: What would be the magic syntax you would want to use?

Comment: @MSN: I was looking to write a function `template <??? F> void foo(F)` which can be called as `foo(bar)` where `bar` is a function template (e.g. `template <typename T> void bar(T)`). `foo` could then call `F` with arguments of various types. I'll leave it up to your imagination as to what might go in the `???` :) This can be made to work if `bar` is a polymorphic function object (i.e. a non-template class with a templated operator()), in which case `foo`'s template parameter would be an ordinary type parameter. [continued in next comment]

Comment: [continued from previous comment] However, I would like to use an existing function template `bar` without adapting it to be a polymorphic function object.

Comment: so something like `template <??? F> void foo(F f) { f(1, 2); f(3.0); }`? You can't refer to a set of function overloads as a single type or template type, unfortunately.

Comment: @MSN: No, more like `template <??? F> void foo(F f) { f(Bar()); f(Moogah()); }` I don't need `???` to refer to a set of function overloads, just a set of instantiations of a single function template. (i.e. the thing I would pass as `f` would NOT be a function with an overload for `Bar` and an overload for `Moogah`; it would be a single function template, which `foo` would then instantiate with parameters of type `Bar` and `Moogah`.

Comment: @MSN: I asked this as a separate question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7033645/is-there-a-generic-way-to-adapt-a-function-template-to-be-a-polymorphic-function

Comment: I came on SO to ask this exact question. Another C++ metaprogramming inconsistency :/

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No.

Comment: @HighCommander4: you can use class templates and call static member functions.

Comment: @Alexandre C.: What I wanted to do was take some function templates that someone else wrote, and adapt them to be polymorphic function objects (without having to declare a separate class for each function template I'm adapting). I don't think that's possible without function template template parameters...

Comment: @HighCommander4: why don't you go with `boost::function` (or C++0x `std::function` / `std::tr1::function`) ? The type erasure they provide should get you out of trouble waters.

Comment: @Alexandre. C: And what would I put `std::function< --HERE-- >`?

Comment: @Alexandre. C: I'm taking this discussion to its own question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7033645/is-there-a-generic-way-to-adapt-a-function-template-to-be-a-polymorphic-function