# boost::bind() with template functions

Tags: c++, boost, boost-bind

How can I `boost::bind()` a template function?

I want this code (inspired by the `boost::bind` [`bind_as_compose.cpp`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/bind/bind_as_compose.cpp) example) to compile and run. Note the evaluation is different than in the `bind_as_compose.cpp` example; `fff()` begins running *before* `kkk()`:

```
template<class F> 
void fff(F fun)
{
   std::cout <<  "fff(";
   fun();
   std::cout << ")";
}

void kkk()
{
   std::cout <<  "kkk()";
}

void test()
{
   fff(kkk);             // "Regular" call - OK
   // bind(fff,kkk)();   // Call via bind: Does not compile!!!
}
```

To print:

```
fff(kkk())
fff(kkk())
```

**Update:**
Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7039474/135862), I got this to work:

```
void (&fff_ptr)(void(void)) = fff;
boost::bind(fff_ptr, kkk)();
```

However, this requires me to explicitly specify the instantiation types, which kinds beats the purpose...

**Update 2**
Ultimately, I wanted to pass the bound object as a nullary callable-type argument to another function like `fff()`. In this case, what would be the explicit types?

Say I have another template function `ggg()`:

```
template<class F> 
void ggg(F fun)
{
   std::cout <<  "ggg(";
   fun();
   std::cout << ")";
}
```

How can I use bind to get this output: `fff(ggg(kkk()))`?
This does not seem to work:

```
boost::bind(fff<void()>, boost::bind(ggg<void()>, kkk))();
```

Comment: @Rapptz: `bind(&fff, &kkk)` doesn't work either.

Comment: You have to explicitly pass the template parameter like boost::bind(foo<Type here>, args). You can check the related links, there are probably quite a lot of dupes.

Comment: You could make `fff` a member function template, and take an advantage of an automatic type deduction

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

template<class F>
void fff(F fun)
{
std::cout << "fff(";
fun();
std::cout << ")" <<  std::endl;
}

void kkk()
{
std::cout << "kkk()";
}

int main()
{
    // "Regular" call - OK
    fff(kkk);
    // you have to specify template parameters:
    std::bind(&fff<void()>, &kkk)();
    return 0;
}
```

output is:

```
zaufi@gentop /work/tests $ g++11 -o bind_test bind_test.cc
zaufi@gentop /work/tests $ ./bind_test
fff(kkk())
fff(kkk())
```

according your second part of the question:

boost::bind(fff, boost::bind(ggg, kkk))();

this wouldn't compile, because the argument of the outer `bind` is not a `void()` type!
it is actually really complex template that definitely **can't be casted** to `void()`

Comment: Is there no way to deduce these automatically based on the argument, i.e. `kkk()`?

Comment: @AdiShavit no. first of all you are going to take an address of a function! at this point there is no call, no arguments, so you have to specify explicitly what instance of `fff` you want to take address of.

Comment: Re: the second part: Exactly. That's why I was looking for a solution with automatic type deduction.

Comment: @AdiShavit it would be relatively easy w/ C++11 and `decltype` :)
but you may try to experiment w/ boost typeof library

Answer (score 0):

Answering myself... seems like `boost::bind` is not the way to go here.
I ended up with this:

```
template <typename Fun>
class FFF_t
{   
public:
   FFF_t(Fun fun): realFun(fun) {}

   void operator()() { invoke(); }

   void invoke() 
   {
      std::cout <<  "fff(";
      realFun();
      std::cout << ")";
   }
private:
   Fun realFun;
};

template<class Fun> 
FFF_t<Fun> fff(Fun fun)
{  return FFF_t<Fun>(fun); }
```

This allows me to write

```
fff(fff(kkk))();
```

which gives `fff(fff(kkk()))` as expected.
`bind()` can still be used as the inner functor as in `fff(fff(bind(some2argFun,1,2))))()`.

What I couldn't figure out was how to make the return type of `invoke()` and `operator()()`'s dependent on the return type of `Fun()` (`void` in the example).

Hat-tip to @Igor R. for his comment that sent me in this direction.