# Functional programming with boost: pass a boost::bind to a boost::bind

Tags: c++, function, boost, functional-programming, boost-bind

I'm attempting to take a functional approach to some code I am writing. In particular, I want to pass a function to another function which does something with it, and to then schedule that latter function on a `boost::asio::io_service`.

I tried the following (inspired by [io_service.hpp](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_0/boost/asio/io_service.hpp)'s definition of `io_service::post`) as `template <typename CompletionHandler> void post(CompletionHandler handler);`):

```
#include <stdio.h>

#include <boost/asio/io_service.hpp>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>

template <typename FUNC>
void foo_then_smile(FUNC handler) {
    handler();
    printf("Smile!\n");
}

void foo(int a, int b, int c) {
    printf("The important answer is %d\n", a + b + c);
}

int main() {
    boost::asio::io_service ioService;

    ioService.post(boost::bind(foo_then_smile, boost::bind(foo, 1, 2, 3)));

    return 0;
}
```

But I get:

```
no matching function for call to 'bind(<unresolved overloaded function type>, boost::_bi::bind_t<void, void (*)(int, int, int), boost::_bi::list3<boost::_bi::value<int>, boost::_bi::value<int>, boost::_bi::value<int> > >)'
```

Followed by a huge list of candidates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And if you can't use c++11, you can turn the function template into a polymorphic function object:

```
struct foo_then_smile
{
    typedef void result_type;

    template <typename FUNC>
        void operator()(FUNC handler) const {
            handler();
            printf("Smile!\n");
        }
};
```

And use it (**note** the `protect` to avoid mixing up the bind unwrappings):

```
ioService.post(boost::bind(foo_then_smile(), 
               boost::protect(boost::bind(foo, 1, 2, 3))));
```

See it **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5c76d87a25376258)**

```
#include <stdio.h>

#include <boost/asio/io_service.hpp>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <boost/bind/protect.hpp>

struct foo_then_smile
{
    typedef void result_type;

    template <typename FUNC>
        void operator()(FUNC handler) const {
            handler();
            printf("Smile!\n");
        }
};

void foo(int a, int b, int c) {
    printf("The important answer is %d\n", a + b + c);
}

int main() {
    boost::asio::io_service ioService;

    ioService.post(boost::bind(foo_then_smile(), boost::protect(boost::bind(foo, 1, 2, 3))));

    ioService.run();
}
```

Prints:

```
The important answer is 6
Smile!
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you are trying to bind to a template function, which doesn't work. You can get around this by replacing foo_then_smile with a functor as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7039474/can-i-use-boost-bind-with-a-function-template).

But for what it's worth; if the compiler you're using supports C++11, you can typically use lambdas in place of bindings. I find their syntax to be cleaner and more readable, and they would let you do an end-run around the problem you're experiencing:

`ioService.post([]() { foo_then_smile( []() { foo(1, 2, 3); } ); });`

Comment: Technically, this is not answering the question. It doesn't say how to pass a bind expression to a bind expression.

Comment: The problem isn't passing bind to bind; it's binding to a template. The link I included explains how to handle that.

Comment: The question, though, is about passing bind to bind. I agree that there were more issues, but that doesn't make the question magically change :)

Comment: The question, as I read it, was "why doesn't this compile." :) I tried to provide two different solutions to the underlying issue.

Comment: +1 from me. the link you posted has essentially the same solution as sehe, though sehe did provide a fully working example which is much appreciated!