# Combination of boost range for_each, bind, copy and a back_inserter fails

Tags: c++, boost, boost-bind, boost-range

I want to copy all the integers contained in `a` into `b`.

```
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <boost/range/algorithm/for_each.hpp>
#include <boost/range/algorithm/copy.hpp>
void test()
{
        std::vector<std::vector<int> > a;
        std::vector<int> b;
        boost::for_each(a, boost::bind(boost::copy, _1, std::back_inserter(b)));
}
```

It looks so simple. I'd like to have a C++ 98 compatible one liner.

Why doesn't this compile? 
I have a long list of error regarding `boost::bind`, which I don't understand, moreover, it is multiple pages long.

The error starts with :

> error C2780: 'boost::_bi::bind_t<_bi::dm_result::type,boost::_mfi::dm,_bi::list_av_1::type> boost::bind(M T::* ,A1)' : expects 2 arguments - 3 provided

Comment: Please define "doesn't work", crash? doesnt compile? if you have an error message please give it.

Comment: It 'doesn't work' because there is 'some error' in it. Uless you are more specific, you won't get better answer.

Comment: Sorry, added more information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a directly related question here: [Can I use (boost) bind with a function template?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7039474/can-i-use-boost-bind-with-a-function-template). The error message in that question is identical, and the problem differs in that their template function is not a library one.

The trick here is that you are intending to bind a template function `boost::copy<>()`, which, according to the linked question, isn't possible because the template function must be instantiated in order to be passed as a function pointer. This is also indicated [here](http://www.radmangames.com/programming/how-to-use-boost-bind), section "*Binding a template function*". So, unfortunately, you need to resort to a rather long construct, which can be slightly shortened with the use of `typedef` (since you're in C++98, no `decltype` is available either):

```
int main()
{
        typedef std::vector<int> IntVec;
        std::vector<IntVec> a;
        IntVec b;
        boost::for_each(a,
            boost::bind(boost::copy<IntVec,
            std::back_insert_iterator<IntVec> >, _1, std::back_inserter(b)));
}
```