# How to program this with variadic templates?

Tags: c++, c++11, variadic-templates

I have never used variadic templates myself, but think I could need them now. Suppose I have a class

```
class A {
  int Kern;
  template<int> void func_a(int, double) const;
  template<int> void func_b(double, double, char) const;
  template<int> unsigned func_c(float, std::vector<int> const&) const;
public
  /* ... */
  void FuncA(int, double) const;
  void FuncB(double, double, char) const;
  unsigned FuncC(float, std::vector<int> const&) const;
};
```

where the definitions of `A::FuncA()` etc. are all of the form

```
void A::FuncA(int i, double x) const
{
   switch(Kern) {
   case 1: return func_a<1>(i,x);
   case 2: return func_a<2>(i,x);
   case 3: return func_a<3>(i,x);
   /* ... */
   }
 }
```

I currently implement this switch with a C-macro

```
#define SwitchKernMacro(KERN,FUNC)   \
switch(KERN) {                       \
case 1: FUNC(1);                     \
case 2: FUNC(2);                     \
case 3: FUNC(3);                     \
/* ... */                            \
}
```

such that

```
void A::FuncA(int i, double x) const
{
#define FuncK(KERN) return func_a<KERN>(i,x);
  SwitchKernMacro(Kern,FuncK);
#undef FuncK
}
```

I like to avoid this C-macro in favour of a variadic template solution, such that the implementation of my functions becomes simply (or similar)

```
void A::FuncA(int i, double x) const
{ return SwitchKern(Kern,func_a,i,x); }    
void A::FuncB(double a, double b, char c) const
{ return SwitchKern(Kern,func_b,a,b,c); }
unsigned A::FuncC(float f, std::vector<int> const&v) const
{ return SwitchKern(Kern,func_c,f,v); }
```

How should the template `SwitchKern` look like?

**EDIT**

there seems to be some confusion about C++ templates and when they can be used. Suppose, I only have the following very simple functions

```
class A {
  int Kern;
  template int> void simple() const;
public:
  void Simple() const
  {
    switch(K) {
    case 1: return simple<1>();
    case 2: return simple<2>();
    case 3: return simple<3>();
    default: return simple<0>();
    }
  }
  /* ... */
};
```

then I can also implement `A::Simple()` via

```
class A {
  /* ... */
  template<int> friend struct simple_aux;
};

template<class T, template<int> class SimpleAux>
void Switch(int K, const T* a) {
  switch(K) {
  case 1: return SimpleAux<1>(a)();
  case 2: return SimpleAux<2>(a)();
  case 3: return SimpleAux<3>(a)();
  default: return SimpleAux<0>(a)();
  }
}

template<int k> struct simple_aux
{
  const A*const a;
  explicit simple_aux(const A*a__) : a(a__) {}
  void operator()() { return a->simple<k>(); }
};

void A::Simple() const
{ Switch<A,simple_aux>(K,this); }
```

However, this solution does not allow for return type different than `void` and for arbitrary arguments to the functions `A::Simple()` (passed to `A::simple<>()`). My question was how to add these functionalities using variadic templates

Comment: Is the first argument to `Func1` determined at compile time or runtime?

Comment: Then you can't use templates.

Comment: If *nothing* is determined at compile-time, there's no way to ever get this with templates. Templates are a compile-time mechanism.

Comment: @SethCarnegie If you looked at the code, you would have seen that function argument *types* (and their number) are known at compile time as usual, but not their *values*.

Comment: @Walter I did look at the code, and what you said doesn't make any difference as far as I can see (which may not be far).

Comment: @Walter: of course YOU DON'T, template parameters **have to** be known at compile time. You can't perform any kind of dynamic binding among a bunch of templates without a switch or stuff like that.

Comment: @akappa I don't what? "*template parameters have to be known at compile time*" we all know that. "*...  without a switch*" **I am using a switch** (as you surely have noted).

Comment: I answered to a comment of yours which, apparently, you removed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that function templates can't be passed to a template, only class templates.  You can work around this with helper classes:

```
template<template<int i> class Helper, typename... Args>
auto SwitchKern(int Kern, const A &a, Args &&...args)
-> decltype((a.*(Helper<0>::func()))(args...))
{
    switch (Kern) {
    case 1: return (a.*(Helper<1>::func()))(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    case 2: return (a.*(Helper<2>::func()))(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    case 3: return (a.*(Helper<3>::func()))(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    }
}

template<int i>
struct FuncAHelper {
    static decltype(&A::func_a<i>) func() { return &A::func_a<i>; }
};

void A::FuncA(int i, double x) const
{
    return SwitchKern<FuncAHelper, int &, double &>(Kern, *this, i, x);
}
```

See also [Is there a generic way to adapt a function template to be a polymorphic function object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7033645/is-there-a-generic-way-to-adapt-a-function-template-to-be-a-polymorphic-function)

Comment: +1 very nice. Is there a way to write a generic helper struct which would work for any function arguments and return type?

Comment: @Walter sort of, using `decltype` - see above.  There's still some boilerplate; because you can't have function template template arguments, you have to write the helper struct by hand, but you could use a macro (!) as `decltype` lets you ignore the signature.

Comment: I eventually got it compiled under gcc 4.7.0 (please allow my edit).

Comment: `std::function` can wrap almost anything, can it not also help here?

Comment: @Walter it can wrap any callable concrete object (incl. a function, pointer, etc.) but it can't wrap a template.

Comment: @Walter: The problem is that `std::function` doesn't wrap templates. It wraps (for example) member function pointers, and you want to wrap member function templates. An instantiated member function template can be used to get a member function pointer, but you *need* to instantiate it.

Comment: So does this mean that there is something that the compiler could do (since the preprocessor can), but the language doesn't allows us to?

Comment: @Walter: The preprocessor is a simple text-replacement tool, so yes, the language itself can't do that.

Comment: @Walter pretty much; there's no real demand for function template template arguments, as you can always wrap in a `struct`.

Answer (score -1):

I think templates are all about compile time solutions and they can't help to solve runtime problems, so if you are using a switch to check a runtime value you can't change to to a template (either variadic or normal).